# PHP, MySqli Dynamic Database Nav

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to make a navigation menu. It's displaying perfectly, but I don't know how to attach a link to it and how to set it active when particular page is opened.

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM menu";
$select_all_categories_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all_categories_query)) {
    $cat_id = $row['cat_id'];
    $cat_title = $row['cat_title'];
    echo "<li><a href='#'>$cat_title</a></li>";
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

for the link you can create a new column in your table for links and call it in your link href

```html
echo "<li><a href='<?php echo $row['yourlink'];?>'>$cat_title</a></li>";
```

for the active page it needs javascript, but I use another trick with css,I create a unique css style only for the child I want in each page

Comment: but how would i set class active

Comment: you dont need it if you use the way I suggested

Answer (score 0):

Well this was what exactly I've been looking for but I was finally able to do it myself.

```
<?php

         $query = "SELECT * FROM menu";
         $select_all_categories_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

         while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all_categories_query)){
            $cat_id = $row['cat_id'];
            $cat_title = $row['cat_title'];
            $cat_active = $row['cat_active'];

            if(isset($_GET['category']) == $cat_id){
                $cat_id == $_GET['category'] ? $cat_active = 'active' : '';
            }

            echo "<li class='{$cat_active}'><a href='{$cat_title}.php?category={$cat_id}'>$cat_title</a></li>";
        }

    ?>
```